# if H is f.g, $Q\lhd_f H$ and $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ then $\bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb Z} \phi^i(Q) \lhd_f H$

Tags: group-theory

I need to prove that if H is finitely generated, $Q\lhd_f H$ (normal of finite index) and $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ then $\cap_{i \in \mathbb Z} \phi^i(Q) \lhd_f H$.

Given that H is f.g and Q is of finite index, I do know that Q is f.g and thus all $\phi^i(Q)$ are f.g . That does not mean however that their intersection is f.g. Other than that I have no clue on how to even approach such a problem and how does H being f.g have anything to do with the intersection being of finite index.

Other than a solution, I would also appreciate any reference to any book which is concerned with these type of topics (the general topic I am trying to study is residual finiteness where these type of questions seem to come up as 'obvious remarks').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sketch solution. There is no need to assume that $Q$ is normal in $H$. If $|H:Q|=r$, then there is a homomorphism $\phi:H \to S_r$ with $\phi(H)$ equal to the stabilizer of the first point.

Since $H$ is finitely generated, there are only finitely many such homomorphisms, so there are finitely many subgroups of $H$ with index $r$. So the intersection of all of them has finite index in $H$ and, in particular the intersection of $\phi(Q)$ for all $\phi \in {\rm Aut}(H)$ has finite index in $H$.

This can be false when $H$ is not finitely generated. For example, if $H$ is a direct prodcut of infinitely many copies of $C_2$, then the intersection of all subgroups of index $2$ is trivial, and all these subgroups can all be mapped to each other by automorphisms of $H$.